# Setting the value of input type month

Tags: javascript

How do I set the value of input element type month with javascript?

```
<input type="month>
```

Couldn't find anything about that in the web.

Comment: What browser are you using because Firefox, IE, and Safari doesn't support it

Comment: Chrome and Edge. Also in smartphone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the value attribute like any other type

```html
    <input  type="month"  value="2017-09">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month

---

If you are looking for JS solution, just like you set value to an input, you can do

```
document.getElementById("abc").value = "2017-09";
```

---

*Notes:*

1) While using it, there must be always year. This is a major annoying thing.

2)Be aware that there are browser issues with it.

> However, there are issues with  because at this time, many major browsers don't yet support it.
>
> We'll look at basic and more complex uses of , then offer advice on mitigating the browser support issue in the section Handling browser support).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month#Handling_browser_support

---

*Suggestion :*

I personally don't like the way it is developed and designed in the current want docs supporting the same

> The best way to deal with dates in forms in a cross-browser way (until all of the major browsers have supported them for a while) is to get the user to enter the month and year in separate controls ( elements being popular; see below for an implementation), or use JavaScript libraries such as the jQuery date picker plugin.

Comment: With js. Not in html.

Comment: @NoamB. Sure. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Your can set value as below,

```js
const monthControl = document.querySelector('#month-control[type="month"]');
monthControl.value = '1978-06';
```

```html
<input type="month" id="month-control">
```

Please consider the [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month#Browser_compatibility)

```
Feature       | Chrome | Edge | Firefox (Gecko) | Internet Explorer | Opera | Safari
Basic support | 20     | 12   | No support[1]   | No support        | 10.62 | No support[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

As Suresh said you can access and update it like any other type of input so :

```
<input type="month" id="month_input">
```

And in your JS :

```
document.getElementById("month_input").value = "2017-09";
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var month = document.getElementsByClassName('month');

for (i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
   month[i].value = '2017-06';
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="month"  >
<input type="text" class="month"  >
```

you can use class also to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can simply the code below to set the current month into your `#month-input-element`.

```
let now = new Date();
    
let currentYear = now.getFullYear();
let currentMonth = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    
$('#month-input-element').val(`${currentYear}-${currentMonth}`);
```